# Outgoing messages are more than incoming messages in Event Hub when using EventProcessorHost

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I am using Azure Event hub. Outgoing messages from Event hub are processed by application using `EventProcessorHost`.
Event hub has one consumer group i.e. `$Default`.
I am seeing outgoing messages are more than incoming messages.
Not sure why outgoing is more than incoming in Event hub.

[image]

Comment: maybe your processors are reprocessing messages either when restarting or when scaling out before certain messages have been properly checkpointed. Your app should be resilient to this. Event Hub is "at least once delivery"

Comment: there is no retry logic written in our app. Not sure EventProcessorHost does retry or not.

Comment: I did not say retry. I said restart. EH-processorhost uses blob storage for checkpointing. Depending on how often you checkpoint, it can happen that you read the same message more than once. this is to be expected in high volume scenarios

Comment: Our code is not using CheckpointAsync() so EH-processorhost does automatically checkpointing . Please confirm.

Comment: nope. it does not do that, except for when closing the connection. if you do not checkpoint yourself in between, you have a no-no!

Comment: then why outgoing is more than incoming ?

Comment: because you are reading some messages more than once.

Comment: now question comes, In which situation it is happening ??

Comment: How many processor hosts are you running with?

Comment: 6 processors are running.